# Error NG8001: 'mat-label' is not a known element

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, mat-form-field

As a title, I'm encountering this error with the mat-label and input. After a day of troubleshooting, I couldn't resolve it. I've read a lot of similar question that has been resolved by importing the right modules. That didn't work. Maybe I've missed something.

I've tried to import/export everything I could need to let these mat-labels and inputs work. I'm starting to think that there is some sort of issue with the versions.

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill" ngForm>
    <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
    <input matInput>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Select</mat-label>                   //even this chunk of simple HTML gets the error! 
    <mat-select>
      <mat-option value="one">First option</mat-option>
      <mat-option value="two">Second option</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill" ngForm>
    <mat-label>Textarea</mat-label>
    <textarea matInput></textarea>
  </mat-form-field>
```

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatButtonToggleModule } from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material/divider';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material/menu';
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatTabsModule } from '@angular/material/tabs';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatMomentDateModule } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';
import { MatCheckboxModule } from '@angular/material/checkbox';
import { NgApexchartsModule } from 'ng-apexcharts';
import { MatRippleModule, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { FuseAlertModule } from '@fuse/components/alert';
import { ExampleModule } from 'app/modules/admin/dashboards/example-module.module';
import { SharedModule } from 'app/shared/shared.module';
import { EditableListRoutes } from './editable-list.routing';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

const modules = [
    CommonModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatRippleModule,
    SharedModule,
    ExampleModule,
    FuseAlertModule,
    NgApexchartsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatMomentDateModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatTabsModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatSortModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatMenuModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatDividerModule,
    MatButtonToggleModule
];

@NgModule({
imports: [...modules,RouterModule.forChild(EditableListRoutes),],
exports: [...modules],
providers: [
    {
        provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE,
        useValue: 'it-IT'
    }
],
schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class EditableListModule {};
```

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ExtraOptions, PreloadAllModules, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { MarkdownModule } from 'ngx-markdown';
import { FuseModule } from '@fuse';
import { FuseConfigModule } from '@fuse/services/config';
import { FuseMockApiModule } from '@fuse/lib/mock-api';
import { CoreModule } from 'app/core/core.module';
import { appConfig } from 'app/core/config/app.config';
import { mockApiServices } from 'app/mock-api';
import { LayoutModule } from 'app/layout/layout.module';
import { AppComponent } from 'app/app.component';
import { appRoutes } from 'app/app.routing';
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { EditableListModule } from './modules/admin/dashboards/editable-list/editable-list.module';

const routerConfig: ExtraOptions = {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',
    preloadingStrategy       : PreloadAllModules,
    relativeLinkResolution   : 'legacy'
};

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports     : [
        BrowserModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, routerConfig),
        EditableListModule,

        // Fuse & Fuse Mock API
        FuseModule,
        FuseConfigModule.forRoot(appConfig),
        FuseMockApiModule.forRoot(mockApiServices),

        // Core
        CoreModule,

        FormsModule,

        // Layout
        LayoutModule,

        // 3rd party modules
        MarkdownModule.forRoot({})
    ],
    bootstrap   : [
        AppComponent
    ],
    schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

```bash
  _                      _                 ____ _     ___ 
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | | 
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | | 
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 11.2.11
Node: 18.12.1
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.2.12
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms     
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                            Version
------------------------------------------------------------    
@angular-devkit/architect          0.1102.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular      0.1102.11
@angular-devkit/core               11.2.11
@angular-devkit/schematics         11.2.11
@angular/cdk                       11.2.11
@angular/cli                       11.2.11
@angular/material                  11.2.11
@angular/material-moment-adapter   11.2.11
@schematics/angular                11.2.11
@schematics/update                 0.1102.11
rxjs                               6.6.7
typescript                         4.1.5
```

Comment: mat-form-field doesn't get highlighted as error btw

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues before. Try importing `MatFormFieldModule` directly into the `AppModule`. That normally has solved the issues that I had.